# Getting correct cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am setting a cookie value via click event:

```
    $("#myModal .modal-body a").click(function() {
        document.cookie = 'town='+$(this).text()+'; path=/';
    });
```

Everything works just fine, but when trying to display this value in html element on the other day (if its necessary):

```
<div>
    <?=$_COOKIE['town']?>
</div>
```

In the browser I get something like `#A=0G` in this div. Firebug shows this value `#A=0G`, but the raw data is correct `town`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post more code? When are you setting your cookie? when are yo u making a request to your server? What order are your operations happening in?

Comment: is <?=$_COOKIE['some']?> meant to be valid php?

Comment: Define "raw data" - where are you getting this "raw data" from?

Comment: `<?= ?>` is the same as `<?php echo ?>`

Comment: Firebug > Cookies > cookieName > raw data tab

Comment: Download jquery.cookie plugin. Use `$.cookie('name', 'value', { path: '/' });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be an encoding issue, what is the origin value of the `town`?

You can try to set the cookie this way:

```
document.cookie = 'town=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).text()) + '; path=/';
```